# Java interface extending an abstract class?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

I am posting a code snippet that does not give any syntax error when an interface extends and abstract class. The interface `audio` extends abstract class `music` in the method `sort()`

```
import java.util.List;
abstract class music {}
public interface audio {}

abstract class play implements Comparable <play> {

    public <audio extends music> void sort (List <music> list){
        //do something 
    }

}
```

I am assuming an interface CAN NOT extend an abstract class. Can any one explain why it is so?

Answer (score 5):

In your example, the second "audio" is not the interface,  but a type parameter to your generic method. You could just as well name it `T`.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand. Your type parameter `audio` is hiding the interface `audio`.

```
public <T extends music> void sort(List<music> list) {
    // do something
}
```