# Can a class inherit from both an Interface and a base class in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

in .Net you can simply do this with the following code

```
Public class MyClass:ISomeInterface, SomeBaseClass
```

Can something similar be done in Java?

The code I have is as follows

```
public class InputHander extends OnTouchListener implements IControlHandler
```

However I get the error "no interface expected here" with regards to OnTouchListener

Comment: Yes of course. Have you gone through a basic Java tutorial, covering inheritance and interfaces?

Comment: Classes don't inherit from interfaces, they just implement them. You can extend (inherit from) a single class, but you can implement multiple interfaces.

Comment: `OnTouchListener` in an interface.

Comment: So if an interface implements another interface does that use the extends keyword instead?

Comment: @coolblue2000 an interface cannot implement an interface. But it can extend other interfaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use the `extends` keyword for class inheritance and `implements` for interface implementation:

```
public class MyClass extends SomeBaseClass implements SomeInterface
```

---

From your question edit, you should use `extends` in class declaration for **class inheritance**. In other words, a class can only extend from another single **class**, not from interfaces. Multiple class inheritance is not allowed. In case you want to implement an interface, use `implements` keyword only. So, your code would be:

```
public class InputHander implements OnTouchListener, IControlHandler
```

More info:

- [Java Tutorials: Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Comment: I get an error in Android Studio saying "No Interface expected here" with regards to the BaseClass.

Comment: @coolblue2000 it would be better if you edit your question and add your current code below the current content to get better help.

Comment: Well, you actually can extend from interfaces, but only in other interfaces.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now as I copied the call from an interface not a class.... Java is not entirely clear at times....

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It takes couple of seconds to try it out:

```
public class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass implements MyInterface
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to prevent the pitfalls and complexities that arise if you have a language that supports *multiple inheritance* (e.g. C++), Java allows you to inherit from exactly one class (using `extends` and that class may or may not be `abstract`) and any number of interfaces (using `implements`).

So this is valid:

```
public class MyClass 
    extends SomeBaseClass 
    implements SomeInterface1, SomeInterface2
```

Java 8 will allow you to have default methods in interfaces but it's implemented carefully enough so as to avoid multiple inheritance ambiguities.

See [Interface with default methods vs Abstract class in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998454/interface-with-default-methods-vs-abstract-class-in-java-8)