# Interface and Baseclass can be combined together?

Tags: oop, inheritance, interface, base-class

After reading [Interface vs Base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class) I understand that Inheritance should be used where there exists a "is-a" relationship and interfaces should be used in "can-do" kind of places.

If that means, base class can only have business objects and interfaces will have only the contracts?

For e.g **Dog** class will have a base class **Animal** with properties like Eye,Nose,Leg etc and interface  **IAnimal** will have "Run", "Jump" etc.

Will design applicable for all the scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

The answers on that question you linked actually say it all. Especially the accepted answer and its first comment. You use an interface to declare the contract and a base class for shared implementation.

I'd consider it a common practice to define interfaces for (almost) everything. An interface can also contain getters and setters and therefore define its subtypes properties. If two or more classes that implement that interface share some implementation, you can moved that to a base class. That base class would then also implement the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct, but I think it relies more on good practices than actual language rules. Please consider the following:

1. In languages that support multiple inheritance (C++) interfaces are just classes with all methods virtual and abstract. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318064/how-do-you-declare-an-interface-in-c)
2. Languages that don't allow multiple inheritance (Java), the most important difference is that a class can have no more than 1 superclass, but can implement an arbitrary number of interfaces. There are also differences in declaring variables (variables are implicitly static and final in Java interfaces) but it's still not a big leap to think of interfaces as of 100% abstract classes.
3. Java 8 introduced default methods (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998454/interface-with-default-methods-vs-abstract-class-in-java-8)), which can kind of blur the obvious distinction between those two.

So while technically it's not true neither that interfaces must **only** define the contract (default methods can implement a fallback behavior in a Java 8 interface) nor that abstract classes **must** define behavior (because a pure abstract class with no implementations can exist), the approach that you described is kind of reasonable and common in real world.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.....

That's a good starting point but it is not right to say that it will be applicable in all scenarios. Systems keep changing and as part of refactoring (http://refactoring.com/catalog/) sometimes interfaces become subclasses and the other way round. Interfaces are good for Mix-ins which you mention as "can-do" kind of behavior and Inheritance where a group of classes share certain properties and possibly some behavior enabling reuse and avoiding code duplication (which is essentially what a IS-A relationship is). You can read more about it in Effective Java by Joshua Bloch (there is an item on Interfaces and Inheritance).

If we take your example, the methods "Run" and "Jump" can be either defined in Animal base class or they can go in an interface as you mention, in fact they can actually go in multiple interfaces too. So you might start off by building a inheritance hierarchy and later refactor them into interfaces as the system evolves.