# Difference between abstract methods and default methods

Tags: java

What is the difference between abstract methods and default methods?

I know this question has been answered before, but not in the way Aristocrates has.

BEFORE KNOWING THE ANSWER FROM "Aristocrates", 
I thought default methods are different from defender methods, and that - default methods are nothing but the abstract methods(without keyword abstract) inside an interface. These two wrong conceptions led this foolish question to be asked. I never meant to trouble the folks by asking an already "well asked and well answered" question.

I wanted to delete this question but I haven't because of two reasons - 1.stackoverflow prevented me, 2.Aristocrates' answer is superb.

Comment: Both are in interface, but default method has an implementation. Simple as that.

Comment: "Sorry if this question has been asked before by anyone else" So you didn't even spend a second on searching for it before asking?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998454/interface-with-default-methods-vs-abstract-class-in-java-8 ?

Comment: They need to bring back "lacks minimal understanding"

Comment: how it is still open?

Comment: @redFIVE Oh yeah.. but minimal understanding of what? Of how to google? Or how to search for questions?

Comment: The thing is that I had a wrong conception of default methods - I thought default methods are different from defender methods, and that - default methods are nothing but the abstract methods(without keyword abstract) inside an interface.
These two wrong conceptions led this foolish question to be asked.
I never meant to trouble the folks by asking an already "well asked and well answered" question.

Answer (score 4):

#### Abstract methods

An abstract method is a method that does not have a method body. Essentially, they are just method declarations and consist only of the method signature.

Example:

```
public abstract void hello(int i);
```

Abstract methods can be in either interfaces or abstract classes. Note that in an interface, methods are abstract by default, and thus the `abstract` modifier is usually left out.

#### Default methods

A default method is a method in an interface that has a "default" implementation provided. In other words, a non-abstract class implementing the interface **would not have to override** a default method defined in the interface.

Example:

```
default public void otherHello(int i) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

#### Example

Here is a valid example of an interface with an abstract and default method and a class implementing the interface:

```
public interface Hello {

    public abstract void hello(int i);

    default public void otherHello(int i) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}

public class Hi implements Hello {

    @Override
    public void hello(int i) {
        System.out.println("Only have to implement this method");
    }
}
```