# How to instantiate an abstract class in Java?

Tags: java, instantiation, abstract

I have a public abstract class named EmployeeFileProcessor, which is also what I am trying to instantiate.  How would I easily fix this code so that I can instantiate this?

```
public abstract class EmployeeFileProcessor
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {   
        EmployeeFileProcessor process = new EmployeeFileProcessor();
        //Non important code here
        process.writeFullTimeEmployee(user_input1, FtCollection[0]);
        //Defined in another class (method writeFullTimeEmployee)
        process.readFulltimeEmployee(user_input1);
        //Defined in another class (method readFullTimeEmployee)
    }
}
```

How would I be able to use the 'process'?

Comment: You cannot instantiate abstract class. Period. That is how java works. If your design requires instantiatation of abstract class, then you need to change your design

Comment: The big question is: Why do you want this class to be abstract in the first place? Perhaps you have a mistaken notion of what "abstract" means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly create an instance of an abstract class. You must first define a class that extends the abstract class and then create an instance of that class.

e.g.

```
public ConcreteEmployeeFileProcessor extends EmployeeFileProcessor {

}
```

You can then create instances of ConcreteEmployeeFileProcessor but reference it using the abstract type.

```
EmployeeFileProcessor instance = new ConcreteEmployeeFileProcessor();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't instantiate an `abstract` class. You have three options :

1. Change `EmployeeFileProcessor` to be a non-abstract class by removing `abstract` from the class declaration.
2. Instantiate an anonymous inner subclass of your class instead : `EmployeeFileProcessor process = new EmployeeFileProcessor() { };` (Not recommended)
3. Change all the methods and fields in `EmployeeFileProcessor` to `static`. This way, you no longer need to instantiate `EmployeeFileProcessor`. (Not recommended unless your class doesn't have state)

In other words, don't create an `abstract` class if you want to instantiate it.

Comment: Changing an abstract class such that it is not abstract is not a way of instantiating an abstract class. The only way to get a reference to an instance of an abstract class is to extend it and then get an instance of the class that extends it.

Comment: Can the downvoter please leave a comment and let me know what is wrong with my answer? As I see it, I have answered the question to the point.

Comment: I down voted your answer because 2, 3 and 4 are by your own words "Not recommended" and point 1 does not give you an instance of an abstract class.

Answer (score 2):

**Abstract class** is a class that you **cannot instantiate** by definition. It is similar to the interface, except for the ability to declare fields and actually implement functions in case they are not overriden *(for Java 8 you can use default methods in the interfaces)*.

Anyway, if you really want to instantiate this class in a default way, you could try to do it like this:

```
EmployeeFileProcessor process = new EmployeeFileProcessor() {};
```

But it's most likely a **very poor** design ;-)

Comment: *It is similar to the interface, except for the ability to declare fields and actually implement functions in case they are not overriden*. Not true. Interfaces can have concrete methods too.

Comment: Yes. The question has been tagged as java so it's always better to mention a specific version of Java if your answer is based on it.

Comment: Ok, changed the answer in order to be more specific. However (it's just my opinion) I can't see big advantages of implementing a method in an interface.

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion. Do read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998454/interface-with-default-methods-vs-abstract-class-in-java-8) answer.

Comment: Thanks, quite right about single inheritance problem ;-)