# Java 8 Interface vs Abstract Class

Tags: java, java-8

I went through this question:
[Interface with default methods vs Abstract class in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998454/interface-with-default-methods-vs-abstract-class-in-java-8)

The following part is not clear to me:

> The constraint on the default method is that it can be implemented
>   only in the terms of calls to other interface methods, with no
>   reference to a particular implementation's state. So the main use case
>   is higher-level and convenience methods.

I tried creating objects of a concrete class (implementation) inside default method and invoked its instance method, it is working fine. i.e, I don't need to use Interface type as reference to the object.

Then what is meant by the quoted paragraph.

Comment: A default method can all other methods defined in the same (or in parent) interface, but it can't access the state of the object, since interfaces can't have a state (i.e. can't have attributes). Asbtract classes don't have this restriction: they can have attributes and can thus read and write them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That sentence means that a `default` method is implemented inside an interface, so it doesn't have any access to a real state of an object but just to what the interface itself exposes, since an interface can't declare instance variables.

For example:

```
abstract class Foo {
 int result;
 int getResult() { return result; }
}
```

This can't be done in an `interface` because you can't have any member variable. The only thing you can do is to combine multiple interface methods, which is what it is specified as convenience / higher-level methods, eg:

```
interface Foo {
  void preProcess();
  void process();
  void postProcess();

  default void processAll() {
    preProcess();
    process();
    postProcess();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Problem is that default methods can only "see" what is declared in the interface itself - not in the implementation class. Any *state* fields that are declared in the class that implements this interface are simply not accessible. But they can access `static final` fields of the interface:

```
interface test {
    static final int x = 3;

    public default void changeIt() {
        System.out.println(x); // this would work
        ++x; // this will fail
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

The Default Method is Just used to gain A Backword_Compatibility Support . Note That The Priority of Default Method is Low Than a Normal Method(or Higher Level Method) So You Cannot Achived the   higher-level and convenience methods