# Default method in interface vs Extending utility class

Tags: java

Let's say  I have a class  A and class B  and both the classes needs to have common methods.
Let's consider below scenario.

```
class A{

    void commonMethod1(){...};
    void commonMethod2(){...};
    
    void someStuff();
   
     }

class B{

    void commonMethod1(){...};
    void commonMethod2(){...};
    
    void someOtherStuff();
   
     }
```

In the above example , both A and B classes have 2 common methods which has same functionality.  Now I would like to know whether to  create a new class called **`Utility`** and include those common methods and let A and B classes extend **Utility** class?

Or  create a interface **`SomeInterface`** and have 2 common methods as default methods with implementation and let class A and  B  implement the  interface?  which is the better design?

I feel implementing interface is preferred than extending a  class ( so class A and class B can still extend some xyz class in future if I go for interface now) .     What are your thoughts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use: Java 8+ interface default method, vs. abstract method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998454/when-to-use-java-8-interface-default-method-vs-abstract-method)

Comment: It's pretty much six of one, half dozen of the other. It depends on if you need to use instance variables or not.

Comment: @Robert I just read that link  before posting this question .. It din't answer my question.   Abstract method is nowhere in my scenario

Comment: @NomadMaker  Design wise , which one is better?  can we make use of default methods here in this case?  Is it right scenario to use default methods in this case?\

Comment: How about both? Use an interface, and then an abstract class that implements the interface?

Comment: Why abstract class?  Any reason?