# Why is Random.nextInt(int bound) specified in Random but not Random.nextInt(int origin, int bound)?

Tags: java

I am currently studying and learning Java.
Now I had to hand in a delivery and used `Random.nextInt(int origin, int bound)` `(java.Util.Random)`.

Now it was reported back to me that my program is not compilable. (probably it was compiled with too low a version by the tester?).
And that's why I searched the internet for the documentation of Random.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/RandomGenerator.html

`Random` inherits from `RandomGenerator` and therefore has access to `nextInt(int origin, int bound)` but in the `Random` class documentation `nextInt(int bound)` is explicitly mentioned but `nextInt(int origin, int bound)` is not. Is this because the former is overwritten by `Random`?

Comment: it is mentioned, under the title: Methods declared in interface java.util.random.RandomGenerator

Comment: `RandomGenerator` is since Java 17, so chances are the compiler being used is an older one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RandomGenerator` which is an interface not a class. This interface has [added in Java 17](https://nipafx.dev/java-random-generator/) ([JEP-356](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/356)). So if you are shipping your code and it is being compiled with an older version of Java it won't work and lead to non-compilation errors.

So instead of using the newest version of Java I would check which version is the desired one to use.

The specific method you are using is a [default method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998454/when-to-use-java-8-interface-default-method-vs-abstract-method) on the `RandomGenerator` and isn't directly implemented in `Random` because of this. The link to the method is still mentioned in the javadoc of `Random` as a referenced method.

Answer (score 0):

It is shown but not the way you think it is.

Take a look at the `Methods declared in interface java.util.random.RandomGenerator` section?

> **Methods declared in interface java.util.random.RandomGenerator**
> isDeprecated, nextDouble, nextDouble, nextExponential, nextFloat, nextFloat, nextGaussian, **nextInt**, nextLong, nextLong

In this section, `nextInt` is a link to [`RandomGenerator#nextInt` with two `int`-parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/RandomGenerator.html#nextInt(int,int)).

The docunentation does not mention all methods the class has in the `All methods`-section but only declared methods (not inherited methods that are not overridden).