# Java: possible wrong abstract class impletaion

Tags: java, abstract-class

I chose this title because I noticed that I did something wrong with the implantation of abstract class but I'm not quite sure what yet.

I created the MoveAble abstract class for training purposes and created the Ball class from it. Also I created a GetPosition() method only for the moveAble class and use it from the ball class.
But when I called GetPosition() on any ball object, i got the position varibale of the Moveable Abstract object instead.

I'm guessing its suppose to be that way, but from my understanding we can't use abstract class anyway, so I need to be able to get the position value of the child class even if I implemented this method only on the parents class.

Note: I'm a beginner java programmer. there is probably a better way to do what I did, but that's what I came out with. I would like to hear what you guys think about it, A if you think it's all crooked and there is a better way for all of this I will be glad to learn it.

Moveable class:

```
public abstract class MoveAble {
    private int[] position = new int[2];
    private int[] velocity = { 1, 1 };

    public int[] getPosition() {
    return position;
    }
    public abstract void move(int width, int height) ;
```

The ball class:

```
public class Ball extends MoveAble{

    private int[] position = new int[2];
    private int[] velocity = { 1, 1 };

    public Ball(int x_position, int y_position) {

        position[0] = x_position;
        position[1] = y_position;
    }

    @Override
    public void move(int width, int height) {
        if (position[0] >  width - 30 || position[0] <  1) {
            velocity[0] *= -1;
        }
        if (position[1] > height - 30 || position[1] <  1) {
            velocity[1] *= -1;
        }
        position[0] += velocity[0];
        position[1] += velocity[1];

    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to inherit the fields 'position' and 'velocity' from the abstract MoveAble class then shadow them in the Ball class?

Comment: You need to override method getPosition. Properties are not overridable to parent class  in java

Comment: @edmarisov That is incorrect.  FIelds are inherited, just as are methods.  (private fields, of course, are not accessible)

Comment: They are not accessible by child in Java unless you mark them as protected. Otherwise you only have access via getter/setter.

Comment: @dsh true, was talking about  private fields

Comment: @duffymo - Not true. Public fields are also accessible by subclasses, and package-private fields may be.

Comment: Who creates classes with public fields?

Comment: @duffymo - That's a separate question. I'm commenting on your first claim.

Comment: @Andy Thomas - I'll amend it by making my assumption explicit: private members in the parent are not accessible by children in Java unless you mark them as public or protected.  In the typical case where the parent and child are in the same package, this is also true for package visible variables.

Comment: The only reason I did it was because I want to make a constructor, and didn't know I can call super constructor instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an interface called IMovable so that you may refer to this object through its interface when you only care about movables...

Now, if you have common code across several subtypes, you can create an Abstract class and invoke its base class code in move, as I have done below, and then add subtype specific move logic in the subtype ... see below

```
public class Ball extends AbstractBall {
    public Ball(int x_position, int y_position) {
        super(x_position, y_position);
    }

    public void move(int width, int height) {
        super.move(width, height);
        System.out.println("SUBTYPE-CLASS MOVE IS CALLED");
    }           

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Ball ball = new Ball(10, 20);
                ball.move(1, 2);
        }
}

abstract class AbstractBall implements IMovable {

    protected int[] position = new int[2];
    protected int[] velocity = { 1, 1 };

    public AbstractBall(int x_position, int y_position) {
        position[0] = x_position;
        position[1] = y_position;
    }

    public void move(int width, int height) {

        System.out.println("BASE-CLASS MOVE IS CALLED");

        if (position[0] >  width - 30 || position[0] <  1) {
            velocity[0] *= -1;
        }
        if (position[1] > height - 30 || position[1] <  1) {
            velocity[1] *= -1;
        }
        position[0] += velocity[0];
        position[1] += velocity[1];
    }           
}

interface IMovable {
    public void move(int width, int height);
}
```

Another benefit of referring to an instance via its interface is that eclipse auto-complete feature will limit it's list of items to the interface methods alone.

[image]

Compare that to the explosion of methods that are displayed in auto-complete when you refer to the same object but through its inheritance hierarchy.

[image]

Which one makes more sense?

```
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Demo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    IPrintable instance1 = new PrintableButton();
    instance1.print();

    PrintableButton instance2 = new PrintableButton();
    instance2.print();
  }
}

interface IPrintable {
  public void print();
}

class PrintableButton extends JButton implements IPrintable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Override
  public void print() {
    System.out.println("Printable Button");
  }
}
```

Comment: The only reason that I made another position variable was to use the constructor I didn't know I can call super constructor instead.
I really not sure why and how and to use an interfaces yet on a new classes, but now I can see that I can put most of my code in the abstract class, and call it with super method on each moveable object.

Comment: As I mentioned in my example, if all you want to do is deal with IMoveable objects, you can refer to your class via its single interface method "move". If you had multiple interfaces, it simplifies the interaction of your class with client classes that use them (clients only use the the interface they are interested in) If you have ever used Swing, you know what a headache it is to find certain "extended" methods but how simple it is to locate "interface" methods" If you are interested I can create an example for you and show you what I mean. Let me know

Comment: Yes @Constantin, that would be great

Comment: OK, I have added the example as promised

Comment: I see that I have to do more studies on the instance mechanic. Still don't quite understand how we can pass different classes to functions by using the same instance .Thanks for all the work you have done to help me.

Comment: I reviewed a few youtube examples and found the following the most comprehensive and easy to understand  tutorial. If there's anything in this particular tutorial you are confused with, tell me the time in the video where you are confused and I will try to clarify it further: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VwIkqLXTP7M

Answer (score 5):

In the code provided,  the fields `position` and `velocity` of `MoveAble` within `Ball` [were hidden](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html). As [rodit pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440723/java-possible-wrong-abstract-class-impletaion#comment50850953_31440723), there is no need to hide the fields in your case. If we remove the fields `position` and `velocity` from `Ball`, we get the expected result.

As to the reason **why** the program does what it does: even if we hide the fields within `Ball`, the method `public int[] getPosition()` stems from `MoveAble` and within `MoveAble`, the fields of `MoveAble` (and those from its superclass) are visible.

One last note: `MoveAble` satisfies more the conditions of an interface than an abstract class. [Here is a discussion about when to use interfaces vs. when to use abstract classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040069/abstract-class-vs-interface-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you (re)defined a different `position` and `velocity` field in class `Ball` that, from within Ball and subclasses, overshadows the fields of the same name inherited from class `MoveAble`.

Remove the `posiition` and `velocity` fields from class `Ball`.  Change the access of the fields to `protected` in your base class `MoveAble`, or alternatively provide protected methods to allow subclasses access to that data.

Comment: For encapsulation and maintainability, prefer *not* to use protected fields.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use references that are abstract types.  (You just can't instantiate an abstract class.)  When you invoke their methods, the runtime behavior is that of the underlying concrete object they point to.

An abstract class can provide default behavior in methods if it's known. My guess is that your abstract class provides behavior that is perfectly acceptable to your `Ball` child class.

This is what polymorphism is all about. Object oriented programming has four important characteristics: abstract data types, encapsulation, polymorphism, and inheritance. Make sure you understand them thoroughly.

I think your mistake is giving both the abstract and concrete classes the same member variables. Where is the reuse in that?  Remove them from `Ball` and make them protected in the parent. Don't override methods in child unless they provide different behavior.