# Name of abstract classes added in Java1.8 or already existing ones

Tags: java, oop, interface, abstract-class

I am revisiting OOPs concepts and still feel confused when to use Abstract Classes and when to use Interfaces. I read 
[Abstract class vs Interface in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040069/abstract-class-vs-interface-in-java) 
&
[Interface with default methods vs Abstract class in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998454/interface-with-default-methods-vs-abstract-class-in-java-8). All other posts on internet are about how to create Abstarct class or Interface or tell theoretical difference when to use what.

**What I am looking for?**

I want to know name of some of the new classes(java1.8) and old classes which are abstract. Thanks!

**What I want to check later?**

Considering Defender Methods introduced since java8 which all abstract classes can be made interface?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AbstractChronology, CountedCompleter are some of the abstract classes added in 1.8
You can get full list of classes and interfaces added in 1.8 here -
http://www.buggybread.com/2015/03/java-8-classes-and-interfaces.html