# C# error cs0534: does not implement abstract member get - although I do

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, get, abstract, implementation

I am new to c#.

I got an interface that I need to implement, including this line in the interface:

```
    public abstract IEnumerable<CardData> AllCards { get; }
```

In my implementation I have this code:

```
    public IEnumerable<CardData> AllCards { 
        get { return cards as IEnumerable<CardData>; }
    }
```

but I get an error saying:

```
error CS0534: 'CardDatabaseImpl' does not implement inherited abstract member 'CardDatabase.AllCards.get'
```

referring to this line in the code.

Any advice?

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNi9q.png)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [documentation for the abstract keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract). You need to use the `override` keyword in the implementing class.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that you're using abstract class, not interface. In this case just `override` this method. Or use interface (without `abstract` keyword), and you will not need to override it, just implement.
[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747517/interfaces-vs-abstract-classes) to get the differences between interface and abstract class